# Compile header file and two .cpp files in Unix/Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, unix, header-files

I am trying to compile 3 files total and can not get it to. The code works in visual++. I have uploaded all 3 files in the same dir and used the following command.

> g++ -o edit Album.cpp lab8.cpp

My file names are listed below 
Album.cpp
Album.h
lab8.cpp

Note the code was written in visual studio C++ and compiled just fine there.

Results in the following

lab8.cpp: In function ‘std::vector read_album_file(std::string)’:
lab8.cpp:142:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream(std::string&)’
  ifstream read (filename);// the ifstream is used to read from the file
                         ^
lab8.cpp:142:25: note: candidates are:
In file included from lab8.cpp:38:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:467:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       basic_ifstream(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:467:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:453:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]
       basic_ifstream() : __istream_type(), _M_filebuf()
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:453:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:427:11: note: std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream&)
     class basic_ifstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:427:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const std::basic_ifstream&’

Comment: Next time you should name your compilers and provide version numbers. Just saying you're on Ubuntu and using GCC is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the constructor prototype of ifstream. It takes a `const char *` and a optional argument, soyou need to write `filename.c_str()`

Comment: Thanks it works now! Wonder why it worked in Visual and not unix with those mistakes.

Comment: No problem. That's a good question I don't know about that, might be a different implementation but you should check

Comment: @Dale Because this is valid in C++11 but not in C++03. It's a different version of C++. If you'd provided the `-std=c++11` flag to GCC then it would have worked (since it looks like you're using GCC 4.8).